# URI is not being matched when testing Springs RequestMatcher

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing

Dependencies in `build.gradle.kts`:

(Spring is actually determining the version numbers, I just explicitly added them here for clarity)

```
implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.6.1")

testImplementation("org.springframework:spring-test:5.3.14")
```

This is the production code being tested:

```
public class RequestResolver {

  public boolean isWhitelisted(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    return getRequestMatcher().matches(httpServletRequest);
  }

  public RequestMatcher getRequestMatcher() {
    return new OrRequestMatcher(
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/error"),
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login**"),
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**logout"),
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/loggedOut"),
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/js/**"));
  }
}
```

And this is the test:

```
public class RequestResolverTest {

  RequestResolver requestResolver = new RequestResolver();

  @Test
  public void testDefaultTimeZone() {
    MockHttpServletRequest mockHttpServletRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest("GET", "/error");
    boolean isWhitelisted = requestResolver.isWhitelisted(mockHttpServletRequest);
    System.out.println(isWhitelisted); // false
  }
}
```

Why is `false` printed out? Shouldn't `/error` match?